# Is there a way to rename several files in hard disk?

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file

I had a bunch of files called, e.g: 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, .....n.png;

I used a tool to compress them and they were added the "-min" suffixe. Now they are:

1-min.png, 2-min.png, 3-min.png, n-min.png

Is there a way to revert them to their original name  avoiding doing it manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your OS and an attempt of code to do this. You have tagged with both Linux and Windows

Comment: I'm using windows, however I have mobaXterm installed, wich allow me to execute linux commands: I tried this  in mobaXterm for testing porpuses (to replace "-min" with "-replace-test"

for f in *-min; do 
    mv -- "$f" "${f%-min}-replace-test"
done

But didn't work. :(

Comment: A bit off topic.. but Windows Subsystem for Linux is a WAY WAY better option than using mobaXterm for running bash commands.

Comment: why don't just use `REN ?.png ?-min.png`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your request is a bit unclear to me but I think that this is what you are asking for.  There are other ways to accomplish this but this method is extendable to all sorts of loop through files called X and do Y to them.

1. It loops through each file in the current directory called *-min.png.
2. It calls a batch function which substitutes "-min" with nothing.
3. It calls the rename command with the old and new name.

`

```
@echo off

for %%f in (*-min.png) do call :renamer "%%f"
goto :EOF

:renamer
Set Input_file=%~1
Set Output_file=%Input_file:-min=%
rename "%Input_file%" "%Output_file%"
goto :EOF
```